# Add vertical line for current year in google visualization

Tags: css, charts, google-visualization, linechart

I need to add one vertical line in current year (x axis)

Configuration Options in my code follows.

```
var options = {
        title: '*****',
        curveType: 'function',
        height: 300,
        legend: { position: 'bottom' },
        chartArea: {width: '80%'},
        pointSize:5,
        width: 500,
        annotation: {
            1: {
                style: 'line'
            }
        }
    }
```

Please note I have used annotation for this, but problem is a bit line alone visible. I need a line for full height .

My Full Code :

```
var options = {
        title: 'Chart',
        curveType: 'function',
        height: 300,
        legend: { position: 'bottom' },
        chartArea: {width: '80%'},
        pointSize:5,
        annotation: { height: 300 }
    }, 

chartData = JSON.parse(window._data.chartData), chartPoint = new Array(), i = 0, j = 0;
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Google');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Yahoo');
    data.addColumn({type: 'boolean', role: 'certainty'});
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    data.addColumn({type: 'boolean', role: 'certainty'});
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
    if(Object.keys(chartData.myMap).length > 0) {
        $.each(chartData.myMap, function(k, v) {
            var val = Math.round(v * 100) / 100;
            chartPoint[i] = new Array();
            var cDate = new Date();
            if(cDate.getFullYear()==k)
            chartPoint[i] = [k, val, null, false, null, false,k];
            else
            chartPoint[i] = [k, val, null, false, null, false,null];
            i++;
        });
        i--;
    }
    if(Object.keys(chartData.myDataMap).length > 0) {
        $.each(chartData.myDataMap, function(k, v) {
            var val = Math.round(v * 100) / 100;
            var val1 = Math.round(chartData.averageMap[k] * 100) / 100;
            if(j==0) {var l = val; j++; } else l = null;
            chartPoint[i] = new Array();
            chartPoint[i] = [k,l,val,false,val1, false, null];
            i++;
        });
    }
    data.addRows(chartPoint);
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

It should be like in this page [[http://jsfiddle.net/NC37X/][3]](http://jsfiddle.net/NC37X/%5d%5b3%5d)

Comment: Update your question with the rest of you chart code (and a sample of data) so we can replicate your chart and see what the problem might be.

Answer (score 3):

I have three forks from your fiddle that might be along the lines of what you are looking for:

```
data.addRow(["G", ' ', 'Foo annotation', 8, 1, 0.5]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Balrog30/W2JWa/1/ -
Using annotations, but just placing a space makes nothing print, but still draws a line.

---

```
        annotations: {
            style: 'line',
            textStyle: {
                opacity: 0
            }
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Balrog30/W2JWa/2/ -
Text is still in annotation, but text opacity set to 0 so that text is totally transparent.

---

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {
    // example copied from Google Visualization API playground,
    // modified for category axis annotations

    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'x');
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotationText'});
    data.addColumn('number', 'Cats');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Blanket 1');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Blanket 2');
    data.addRow([{v: 0, f:"A"}, null, null, 1, 1, 0.5]);
    data.addRow([{v: 1, f:"B"}, null, null, 2, 0.5, 1]);
    data.addRow([{v: 2, f:"C"}, null, null, 4, 1, 0.5]);
    data.addRow([{v: 3, f:"D"}, null, null, 8, 0.5, 1]);
    data.addRow([{v: 4, f:"E"}, null, null, 7, 1, 0.5]);
    data.addRow([{v: 5, f:"F"}, null, null, 7, 0.5, 1]);
    data.addRow([{v: 6, f:"G"}, null, null, 8, 1, 0.5]);
    data.addRow([{v: 7, f:"H"}, null, null, 4, 0.5, 1]);
    data.addRow([{v: 8, f:"I"}, null, null, 2, 1, 0.5]);
    data.addRow([{v: 9, f:"J"}, null, null, 3.5, 0.5, 1]);
    data.addRow([{v: 10, f:"K"}, null, null, 3, 1, 0.5]);
    data.addRow([{v: 11, f:"L"}, null, null, 3.5, 0.5, 1]);
    data.addRow([{v: 12, f:"M"}, null, null, 1, 1, 0.5]);
    data.addRow([{v: 13, f:"N"}, null, null, 1, 0.5, 1]);

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(data, {
        curveType: 'function',
        width: 500,
        hAxis: {
            ticks: [{v:6, f:"G"}, {v:10, f:"K"}]
        },
        height: 400,
        vAxis: {
            maxValue: 10
        },
        annotations: {
            style: 'line'
        }
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Balrog30/W2JWa/3/ -
The third one changes the horizontal axis to a continuous type axis so that I can add ticks.  This only works if your x-axis is numberic or date/time in nature.  This also kind of messes up your axis labeling because the labeling is tied to the ticks, but I'm not really sure what you're trying to display, so it may or may not matter to you.

Comment: It's important that the annotations are at the beginning of the column list, otherwise the line won't be full height.

Comment: The provided jsfiddle didn't work for me but after fiddling around a bit I got it to work: https://jsfiddle.net/6zahewst/6/